# Assigning generic function to generic interface

Tags: typescript

Why is the code below not giving me error ?

why is Typescript allowing me to assign a generic function with a different call signature to the generic interface?

```
interface GenerationIndentityFn{
    <T, U>(args1: T, arg2: U): T;
}

function identityf<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}
let myfunc: GenerationIndentityFn = identityf;  // no error
```